# Where is the landing pad SpaceX used to land a first stage on Dec 21, 2015?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, landing

My Googling skills may be bad, but I have found no map or reference for the Spacex landing pad location. Probably somewhere near Cape Canaveral, but where?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new [Landing Zone 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landing_Zone_1), is the old LC-13, at the south end of Missile Row. Interestingly the initial SpaceX name was Landing Complex 1 (LC-1) which was confusing and just before this landing the sign was renamed to Landing Zone 1, LZ-1, less confusing.

Wikipedia has been updated, so that Launch Complex 13 now redirects to Landing Zone 1, which is kind of fun!

Here is a [link on Google Maps](https://www.google.ca/maps/place/Launch+Complex+13/@28.4883142,-80.5624057,7306m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m2!3m1!1s0x88e0a4802dc1919f:0x98f792466f190cfd!6m1!1e1?hl=en), which is not yet updated with imagery showing the LZ-1 configuration.

Here is an image of the various launch complexes at Cape Canaveral. You can see down at the bottom end that LC-13 is shown as Inactive in 2003, which is true.

[image: Map of Cape Caneveral Launch Complexes]

The launch was from LC-40, further north, and SpaceX has a lease on LC-39A, for manned launches and Falcon Heavy launches.